# Divergence of gauge kinetic coupling at the AdS boundary

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization, action, ads-cft

This is the Einstein-Maxwell-Dilaton Gravity action:
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{EM} =  -\frac{1}{16 \pi G_5} \int \mathrm{d^5}x \sqrt{-g}  \ [R - \frac{f(\phi)}{4}F_{MN}F^{MN} -\frac{1}{2}D_{M}\phi D^{M}\phi -V(\phi)]\,,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $G_5$ is the Newton's constant in five dimensions, $F_{MN}$ is the field strength tensor of $U(1)$ gauge field $A_M$, and $L$ is the AdS radius. Moreover, $f(\phi)$ is the gauge kinetic function that acts as coupling between $U(1)$ gauge field and dilaton field $\phi$, and $V(\phi)$ is the potential of the dilaton field.

To introduce the magnetic field, we're taking the following ansatz:
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & ds^2=\frac{L^2 e^{2A(z)}}{z^2}\biggl[-g(z)dt^2 + \frac{dz^2}{g(z)} + dx_{1}^2+ e^{B^2 z^2} \biggl( dx_{2}^2 + dx_{3}^2 \biggr) \biggr]\,, \nonumber \\
& & \phi=\phi(z), \ \  F_{MN}=B dx_{2}\wedge dx_{3}\,,A(z)=-a z^2
\end{eqnarray*}
By solving the equation of motions, we obtained the metric function $g(z)$ and the gauge kinetic function $f(\phi)$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(z) &=& 1 - \frac{ \int_0^z , d\xi \ \xi^3 e^{-B^2 \xi^2 -3A(\xi) } }{\int_0^{z_h} , d\xi \ \xi^3 e^{-B^2 \xi^2 -3A(\xi) }}\\
f(z) &=& g(z)e^{2 A(z)+2 B^2 z^2} \left(-\frac{6 A'(z)}{z}-4 B^2+\frac{4}{z^2}\right)-\frac{2 e^{2 A(z)+2 B^2 z^2} g'(z)}{z}
\end{eqnarray*}
In our model, everything is working fine except that $f(z)$ diverges at the boundary $(z \rightarrow 0)$.

Will the divergence of the gauge kinetic function at the boundary affect the completeness of our model? If it does, how to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me how you can deduce that $f(\phi)$ is divergent at $z\to0$, if the other functions involved are not known, but since the fundamental quantity of your theory is $f(\phi)F_{MN}F^{MN}$ as long as this is finite your theory is fine.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to state the other functions. I will edit my question to explain the divergence.

Comment: @codebpr just check every scalar in your action. If any of them is singular at $z\to0$ then your theory does not hold at this point.